# How to use KML Network link of google fusiontable in android maps with Current position of user on map?

Tags: android, android-intent

Friends I have created google fusiontable kml network link also i have mapview link of google fusiontable but how to use kml network link or or mapview of google fusion table in android with user cureent location. Any one idea how to use kml network link or mapview link of goggle fusion table in android? please help me.